# C++ can a reference of pointer take null?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, generics, reference

Given the following code:

```
template<class S, class T>
class node {
public:
    S key;
    T value;
    node<S, T> *right_node, *left_node, *parent_node, *nearest_right_node, *nearest_left_node;
    int height;

public:
    template<typename, typename> friend
    class avl_tree;

    node() = default;

    node(const S *key, const T *value, node<S, T> *right_node = nullptr, node<S, T> *left_node = nullptr,
         node<S, T> *parent_node = nullptr, node<S, T> *nearest_right_node = nullptr,
         node<S, T> *nearest_left_node = nullptr) : key(*key),
                                                    value(*value),
                                                    right_node(right_node),
                                                    left_node(left_node),
                                                    parent_node(parent_node),
                                                    nearest_right_node(nearest_right_node),
                                                    nearest_left_node(nearest_left_node),
                                                    height(0) {
    }

    ~node() = default;
};
```

Can I replace the pointers in the c'tor for `value` and `key` with references and still able to give `key` and `value` a value of nullptr? (for example if S is int*)?

Update:

```
int* x;

    void update_x(int &new_x)
    {
        x=new_x;
    }
```

can I call `update_x(null_ptr)`

Comment: The `key` and `value` pointers you're passing into your constructor right now *already* can't be null. If they are, you'll dereference them anyways and get Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a reference and a pointer?  This is not an obscure corner of the language, its meat-and-potatoes.  I think you could benefit from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: `key(*key)` This is simply always wrong, no ifs or buts.

Comment: The update is simply invalid. It will not compile. You cannot use it in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. why do you say it is always wrong? Unless the paramter `key` is a `nullptr` it is ok-ish. "wrong" in the sense that the code would not pass a review I do agree

Comment: Questions should not be edited so drastically that they invalidate existing answers. If need be, post a new question

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It is wrong because it is a wrong tool for the job. The function says it accepts a pointer. Why? It accepts a pointer because it doesn't know any better, not because it needs a pointer. Thus it lies (inadvertingly)  about what it needs.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. ok, we are on the same side actually. I got nitpicked recently quite stubbornly for calling something "wrong" that was neither a compiler nor a runtime error, maybe I am still a bit affected by that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your `node` class has members `S key` and `T value`, and constructor parameters `const S *key` and `const T *value` which initialize the members using `key(*key)` and `value(*value)`, respectively, which will *copy* the input values into the members.

If a `nullptr` is passed in to either parameter, the code has *undefined behavior* when dereferencing the `nullptr`.

There is no reason for the parameters to be pointers at all.  They should be passed in either **by value**:

```cpp
template<class S, class T>
class node {
public:
    S key;
    T value;
    ...

public:
    ...

    node(S key, T value, ...) : key(key), value(value), ... { }
    // or: node(S key, T value, ...) : key(std::move(key)), value(std::move(value)), ... { }

    ...
};
```

Or **by const reference**:

```cpp
template<class S, class T>
class node {
public:
    S key;
    T value;
    ...

public:
    ...

    node(const S& key, const T& value, ...) : key(key), value(value), ... { }

    ...
};
```

Or **by rvalue reference**:

```cpp
template<class S, class T>
class node {
public:
    S key;
    T value;
    ...

public:
    ...

    node(S&& key, T&& value, ...) : key(std::move(key)), value(std::move(value)), ... { }

    ...
};
```

If `S` or `T` are defined as pointer types, then a `nullptr` can be passed in as the *value* to be assigned to the `key`/`value` members, eg:

```cpp
node<int, type*> *n = new node<int, type*>(1, nullptr);
```

```cpp
type t;
node<int, type*> *n = new node<int, type*>(1, &t);
```

But if `S` and `T` are not pointer types, they should not be passed in as pointers:

```cpp
type t;
node<int, type> *n = new node<int, type>(1, t);
```

```cpp
type t;
node<int, type> *n = new node<int, type>(1, std::move(t));
```

```cpp
node<int, type> *n = new node<int, type>(1, type{});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code boils down to:

```
void foo(int* x) {
   int y = *x;
}
```

Passing a `nullptr` to `foo` will cause undefined behavior because you shall not dereference a `nullptr`.

Using a reference is possible but will not change that fact:

```
void bar(int*& x) {
    int y = *x;
}
```

This is passing the pointer by reference.

```
int a;
int* p = &a;
bar(p);
```

Now `x` in `bar` is a reference to the pointer to `a`. However, you cannot pass a nullpointer to `bar`, because `bar` is dereferencing the pointer. Some malicious code could do this:

```
int* p = nullptr;
bar(p);           // DO NOT DO THIS !!!
```

And then `int y = *x;` will invoke undefined behavior.

If the function expect to always get a valid object it should take it by reference:

```
void foo_bar(int& x) {
    int y = x;   // no danger, all fine
}
```

---

References cannot refer to nothing. They must be initialzed:

```
int& x; // ERROR !
int y;
int& z = y;  // OK, z refers to y
```

Pointers on the other hand not always point to a valid pointee:

```
int* p;       // not initialized, no (big) problem
p = nullptr;  // still not pointing to an int
int q;
p = &q;       // now p points to an int
```

References cannot refer to nothing, thats why when "nothing" is not a valid parameter you should prefer references over pointers. In your case you always require `*value` to be valid, hence `value` always must point to a `S` and you should use a reference instead to avoid the above mentioned problem.

---

Concerning your update:

> ```
> int* x;
>
>     void update_x(int &new_x)
>     {
>         x=new_x;
>     }
> ```
>
> can I call update_x(null_ptr)

No. You cannot. `nullptr` is not an `int`. A reference to an `int` always references an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I mean I will explain

Comment: Then why in my last question you and another guy told me to change c'tor pointers to references? that doesn't make sense if key can be null

Comment: @whiteforce that is actually in the answer. Look at `bar(int*& x)`. In principle you could pass it a `nullptr` then `x` is a reference to a `nullptr`, but it will blow up as soon as you dereference it (in the line `int y = *x;` (and thats basically what happens in your constructor)

Comment: Actually it is the rvalue-to-lvalue conversion on a null reference that is illegal.  Creation of a null reference (by dereferencing a null pointer) is not undefined behavior as long as it remains an unused lvalue.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 in your answer, `void bar(int*& x) ... int a; bar(&a);` doesn't compile, as the reference can't be bound: "*error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int*’*" It would have to be more like this instead: `int a; int *b = &a; bar(b);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks. Usually I do test my code in answer, but I was a bit sloppy here. Fixed now (i hope)